# How do I get the public key that "Enable TLS" wants. Openssl doesn't create pem formated public key for self-signed certificates

Tags: ssl, apache-kafka, certificate, kubernetes-helm, bitnami

I'm attempting use "Use Your Own TLS Certificate" the "Use PEM Format" of the following web page: https://docs.bitnami.com/kubernetes/infrastructure/kafka/administration/enable-tls/

I'm trying to "helm install" kafka with TLS certificates using the above instructions which wants me to use the certificate, public key, and private key of the self-signed certificate I created using openssl. But, openssl does not create a public key. So, I believe this is why my "helm install" never works, i.e. the kafka-0 pod always ends up with a Status of 'CrashLoopBackOff". And, when I read the pods log file I see that the reason it crashed was because of 'Invalid PEM keystore configs' which I believe was caused by me using the CSR file, created by openssl as the public key file that kafka wants. The CSR file does contain the public key but it also contains other information.

Comment: What files did you create using openssl? What were the openssl commands? Where did you put these files? There is no reason to have, or use, a CSR anywhere. The CSR is an intermediate file used in *the process* of getting a certificate signed by a certificate authority.

Answer (score 0):

The following openssl command will create a public key from the CSR:
*sudo openssl req -in cert.csr -noout -pubkey -out public.key*
where 'cert.csr' is the CSR file.